# ctrl+backspace listener not working in swt editor

Tags: java, swt, keylistener, e4

I have created listeners for ctrl+ del and ctrl+ backspace got deleting proceeding and preededing words.the ctrl+del listener is working fine by deleting the proceeding word but ctrl+backspace is not working.I am not able to find what is the issue.
The code for listener is as follows

```
 editor.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 


                     if(e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode == 46){   
                         System.out.println("after the word");

                         editor.invokeAction(ST.DELETE_WORD_NEXT);


                       } 

                     if(e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode == 8){   
                         System.out.println("before the word");

                         editor.invokeAction(ST.DELETE_WORD_PREVIOUS);


                       } 
                 }
```

The code for editor is as follows

The code for the editor

```
editor = new StyledText( this, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL );
editor.setLayoutData( new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH) );
editor.setFont( new Font(Display.getDefault(),"Cambria", 10, SWT.NORMAL) );
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you not getting the keystroke? Or is it 'delete work previous' that is not working?

Comment: Note that you must dispose of any font you create or you will eventually run out of resources. If you are using an e4 RCP you can use CSS styling.